# Covariance Matrix of Zero Mean Data

Tags: statistics, covariance

Given a covariance matrix is there a way to tell if it came from zero mean data?

Comment: Do you know $E[X_i^2]$?

Comment: Nope, I  just have the covariance matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot tell based on the covariance matrix alone, for a simple reason: adding something to the mean does not alter the covariance matrix.